# Infinite marquee scroll is not working - GSAP and Vue

Tags: vue.js, animation, infinite-scroll, gsap

I'm making infinite marquee scroll using GSAP and Vue 2.0. It should look like that: https://codepen.io/bappla/pen/abpyGQy

Why does infinite text scrolling to the left work but not to the right?

This should illustrate the problem: [image]

As you can see, "looking good" text looks fine, while "not looking good" scrolling text breaks off and resets.

That's my template inside vue:

```vue
<div
    id="thats-me-block"
    class="text-white flex flex-col text-[64px] font-semibold leading-[50px] text-center overflow-hidden relative"
  >
    <div class="thats-me-inner opacity-50">
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thats-me-inner opacity-[62.5%]">
      <span class="thats-me-span left">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span left">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thats-me-inner opacity-75">
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thats-me-inner opacity-[87.5%]">
      <span class="thats-me-span left">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span left">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
    </div>
    <div class="thats-me-inner">
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
      <span class="thats-me-span right">THAT'S ME</span>
    </div>
    <canvas ref="canvas" class="absolute"></canvas>
  </div>
```

That's my gsap functions animating texts infinitly:

```js
const loaded = () => {
  gsap.to('.thats-me-span.right', {
    xPercent: 100,
    duration: 5,
    ease: 'linear',
    repeat: -1,
  })
  gsap.to('.thats-me-span.left', {
    xPercent: -100,
    duration: 2,
    ease: 'linear',
    repeat: -1,
  })
}
```

Thank you for any help!